# Trigger a specific feature in Olympe SDK

Tags: python

I'm using the Olympe SDK to connect to an Anafi-AI drone on the Parrot Sphinx simulator. My aim is to find out the drone's firmware version. I'm looking to retrieve the drone's firmware version using the Olympe SDK. While I've gathered most of the code, I'm unsure about initiating the AllSetting message. To access additional data from the drone, other messages need to be triggered. Can you guide me on how to activate an Olympe message effectively? This is particularly important for obtaining the firmware version.

I am required to utilize this event message.:

```
    olympe.messages.skyctrl.SettingsState.ProductVersionChanged(software=None, hardware=None, _policy='check_wait', _float_tol=(1e-07, 1e-09))
```

This event message is activated by the ALLsettings command:

```
    olympe.messages.skyctrl.Settings.AllSettings(_timeout=10, _no_expect=False, _float_tol=(1e-07, 1e-09))
```

The code's structure should resemble this example:

```
class frimware_status:
        def get_firmware_version(self):
            drone = olympe.Drone(DRONE_IP)
            drone.connect()
            # here i should trigger AllSettings
            drone.get_state(ProductVersionChanged)["software"]
```

If I don't activate the AllSettings, I'll encounter an uninitialized ProductVersionChanged error.